# Finding which version of valgrind is running

Tags: c++, c, valgrind, avx

in C/C++, I can include valgrind headers to know at runtime whether or not my software is running on valgrind :

```
#include <valgrind/valgrind.h>

bool RunningOnValgrind() 
{
    return RUNNING_ON_VALGRIND ? true : false;
}
```

This is documented in the [valgrind manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html).

I would like to be able to know if the valgrind I am being run on supports AVX instructions. How do I write a function that returns this information ?

From [valgrind release notes](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.news.html), I known that these are supported from version 3.8 onwards.  Hence one solution would be to spawn a process to execute *valgrind --version* and then parse the output but there must be a better way.

Answer (score 3):

If you look in valgrind/valgrind.h, you see you can check valgrind version number this way after including valgrind.h:

```
  #if defined(__VALGRIND_MAJOR__) && defined(__VALGRIND_MINOR__)   \
      && (__VALGRIND_MAJOR__ > 3                                   \
          || (__VALGRIND_MAJOR__ == 3 && __VALGRIND_MINOR__ >= 8))
    /* code to say avx is supported */
  #endif
```

This has many limitations, however: it assumes you are using a globally-installed version, and that your path isn't pointing to some personal, user-built valgrind that isn't in the default location (which I have done) and it also assumes that you are building on the machine where you will run valgrind, and not shipping around a pre-built executable (which in my experience is something that happens often) so you can't rely on that.

With that in mind, spawning a sub-process with `valgrind --version` and checking the output may truly be the best alternative.

Comment: The limitations you are stating are the exact reason why I need to get the version at runtime and not compile time !

Comment: Makes sense to me, as my post implied.  However, it looks like valgrind doesn't have an API you can call at runtime to retrieve the major/minor version numbers, so running it in a subprocess and parsing the output is probably what you are left with - and hope that you aren't running your program in valgrind with the `--trace-children=yes` option (as having valgrind "valgrind itself" to get the version number may be sloooow...)

Comment: Submitted a patch to valgrind's bug tracker : https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=338365. Let's see what happens now...

Comment: Eight years later, the patch submitted  to valgrind to get the version number at runtime has not been accepted (nor rejected)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **VALGRIND_MAJOR** to detect the version in runtime, or use --version flag to get the exact version.

Comment: __VALGRIND_MAJOR__ gives the version used at compile time, not the runtime version of valgrind.

Comment: VALGRIND_MAJOR is defined at compile time, you could us it in runtime.